# query nutch 2 table result from cassandra 2 dose not look right

Tags: java, cassandra, nutch

I am using Nutch 2.2.1 and Cassandra 2 to craw pages. for a test i just inject one url to Cassandra and explore the database.

Using CQL i can query the table in the webpage keyspace

cqlsh:simplex> select * from webpage.f;

```
 key                                  | column1 | value
--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------
 0x6564752e6373752e7777773a687474702f |  0x6669 |         0x00278d00
 0x6564752e6373752e7777773a687474702f |    0x73 |         0x3f800000
 0x6564752e6373752e7777773a687474702f |  0x7473 | 0x00000145a266703e
```

which is fine if i convert those hex bytes to string. the key will be the reverted url.

then i write java code to read the table f using datastax java driver 2 (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/whatsNew2.html)

i followed the sample code

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("10.20.104.181").build();
Session session = cluster.connect();
ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM webpage.f");
for (Row row : results) {

            System.out.println("Key");
        System.out.println(toStrFromByteBuffer(row.getBytes("key")));
        System.out.println("column1");
        System.out.println(toStrFromByteBuffer(row.getBytes("column1")));
        System.out.println("value");
        System.out.println(toStrFromByteBuffer(row.getBytes("value")));

}
cluster.close();



public static String toStrFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer)
    {
        byte[] ar=buffer.array();
        System.out.println(ar.length);
        return new String(ar,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
```

the result is below. You can see row.getBytes("key") returns a whole row data not a specific column value.

Could some master help on this?

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem now. I am using Nutch 2.2.1 and Cassandra 1.2.9. I do not know why data are stored in hex format. I would like to have it in UTF-8. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nutch stores its data in the f column family as *BytesType*. The column names are stored as *UTF8Type*.
If you want to get the data as a String you have to convert it first. A row is completely stored in the ByteBuffer. In your example you convert the whole byte buffer to String what gives you the whole row. When you select one row, you get the current position an limit of that row. So you have to read from begin:buffer current pointer position to buffer limit. For example to get the websites content in the "cnt" field:

```
// This is the byte buffer you get from selecting column "cnt"
ByteBuffer buffer;
int length = buffer.limit() - buffer.position();

byte[] cellValue = new byte[length];

buffer.get(cellValue, 0, length);

return new String(cellValue, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```